# Python update lines

Tags: python

I have this code.

```
START_STAT =(
            [ 4, 3, 6, 3, ],
            [ 3, 3, 4, 6, ],
            [ 3, 5, 5, 3, ],
            [ 4, 6, 3, 3, ],
            [ 4, 3, 6, 3, ],
            [ 3, 3, 4, 6, ],
            [ 3, 5, 5, 3, ],
            [ 4, 6, 3, 3, ],
            )
```

And i want to update one with one more line

```
START_STAT.update{[ 6, 2, 2, 6, ]}
```

What is wrong there ?
I tried also with + but same , error.

```
START_STAT +={[ 6, 2, 2, 6, ]}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: For one, the following brackets: `{}` and `()` shouldn't be there, they make it a set or dict. Also, you have an extra `,` after each last element which is untidy (but doesn't break anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`START_STAT =(..)`

Tuple is `immutable`.

You could use `list` for that purpose:

```
START_STAT = []
START_STAT.append([ 6, 2, 2, 6, ])
```

Comment: That's not even a `dict` being added, it's an attempt to generate a `set` with a `list` as its sole member, which fails with a `TypeError`.

Comment: Heh, don't work with append. <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>:'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @Ramy change initial tuple to list

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `list` instead of a `dict`, as Xi_ suggested, then you can also do this:

```
import numpy as np
START_STAT =(
            [ 4, 3, 6, 3, ],
            [ 3, 3, 4, 6, ],
            [ 3, 5, 5, 3, ],
            [ 4, 6, 3, 3, ],
            [ 4, 3, 6, 3, ],
            [ 3, 3, 4, 6, ],
            [ 3, 5, 5, 3, ],
            [ 4, 6, 3, 3, ],
            )

lst = ([ 6, 2, 2, 6, ])
np.vstack((START_STAT,lst))
```